# Generic decorator with Windsor

Tags: c#, .net, generics, castle-windsor

I'm trying to figure out how to register the following decorator scenario with Castle Windsor. I have the following interface:

```
public interface ICalculate<T> where T : class 
{
   void Calculate(T value);
}
```

And a couple of implementations where the last one is a decorator.

```
public class FooCalculator : ICalculate<Foo> 
{
   public void Calculate(Foo value)
   {
       // do something here with the value..
   }
}

public class BarCalculator : ICalculate<Bar>
{
    public void Calculate(Bar value)
    {
       // do something else here....
    }
}

public class CalculatorDecorator<T> : ICalculate<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly ICalculate<T> _calculator;

    public CalculatorDecorator(ICalculate<T> calculator)
    {
         _calculator = calculator;
    }

    public void Calculate(T value)
    {
       // do for example some logging...
       _calculator.Calculate(value);
    }
}
```

This is my registration code

```
container.Register(Classes.FromAssembly()
                          .BasedOn(typeof(ICalculate<>))
                          .WithService.Base());
```

When i request one of the implementations by their generic interface I want Windsor to resolve the CalculatorDecorator with the requested implementation injected in the constructor.

```
// I would like calculator to be CalculatorDecorator<Foo> in 
// this case but it is FooCalculator.
var calculator = container.Resolve<ICalculate<Foo>>();

// The same goes for this one...
var calculator = containr.Resolve<ICalculate<Bar>>();
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

It works if I do like this

```
container.Register(Component.For<ICalculate<Foo>>()
                            .ImplementedBy<CalculatorDecorator<Foo>>(),
                   Component.For<ICalculate<Foo>>()
                            .ImplementedBy<FooCalculator>());

container.Register(Component.For<ICalculate<Bar>>()
                            .ImplementedBy<CalculatorDecorator<Bar>>(),
                   Component.For<ICalculate<Bar>>()
                            .ImplementedBy<BarCalculator>());
```

But I would prefer to register all components if it's possible.

Comment: I got it working with a bit of reflection. I did scan my assembly manually and then registered all interfaces that i found with the decorator.

Answer (score 0):

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssembly()
                      .BasedOn(typeof(ICalculate<>))
                      .WithService.Base());
```

Did you try this? We had a similar situation and this worked for us.

**UPDATE**

I don't think this is possible because you'll create a circular dependency.
I did get it working like following:

Registration

```
 var container = new WindsorContainer();


        container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IDecorator<>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(CalculatorDecorator<>)));

        container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
                               .BasedOn(typeof (ICalculate<>))
                               .WithService.Base());



        var fc = container.Resolve<IDecorator<Foo>>();
        var bc = container.Resolve<IDecorator<Bar>>();
```

Interfaces:

```
   public interface ICalculate<T> where T : class
{
    void Calculate(T value);
}

public interface IDecorator<T> : ICalculate<T> where T : class
{

}
```

Implementation:

```
public class FooCalculator : ICalculate<Foo>
{
    public void Calculate(Foo value)
    {
        // do something here with the value..
    }
}

public class BarCalculator : ICalculate<Bar>
{
    public void Calculate(Bar value)
    {
        // do something else here....
    }
}

public class CalculatorDecorator<T>: IDecorator<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly ICalculate<T> _calculator;

    public CalculatorDecorator(ICalculate<T> calculator)
    {
        _calculator = calculator;
    }

    public void Calculate(T value)
    {
        // do for example some logging...
        _calculator.Calculate(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't get that to work. It still resolves the BarCalculator when I request ICalculate<Bar>. I think AllTypes is the same as Classes in the registration api.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work either.  Has anyone been able to achieve this?